# Include a Maven dependency only if it exists

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem, I have a project which is based in a system that includes modules. This modules are other maven projects and are referenced from system POM. My problem is I'm sharing  the system project with a workmate and we've got different modules.

So, is there a way to tell Maven that I want to include a module referenced in my POM only if this module exists? I mean, without compilation failure.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can declare it as optional. http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and activate them on `file/exists` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use dependencyManagementis  to pull all the dependency information into a common POM file, simplifying the references in the child POM file.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, depending on what you can do/want to achieve.

One approach is to install a Maven repository server at your company (in your local LAN or in a LAN that you and your colleague share). Build the system and then [deploy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) the modules to the server.

In your build, you can add this new server like this ([documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)):

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Or you can both copy the base system and build it locally with `mvn install`. That will copy all artifacts into your local cache.

From there, you can reference them as usual. You don't need to include all the modules; just the ones you really need. That way, you and your friend don't have to use the same dependencies.